# How to redirect all pages inside folder and remove .html prefix

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have found many 301 htaccess redirects examples but i need something specific and dont know how to build that exact redirect rule... the site i am build this for is a wordpress site.

**Example:**

```
http://www.example.com/article/some-article-01.html
http://www.example.com/article/data-analysis.html
http://www.example.com/article/another-page.html
```

**To redirect to:**

```
http://www.example.com/article/some-article-01/
http://www.example.com/article/data-analysis/
http://www.example.com/article/another-page/
```

looking for one htaccess rule that works in wordpress...
a pointer to relevant data would be accepted hapily. cant seem to find the right search query. An example code would be of course much more easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file as **very first rule** just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(article/[^.]+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

If it works for you then change `302` to `301` to make it permanent redirect.

Comment: This is just an example... how would i set it if i dont have the same page name (fixed my question)  - thanks for your help ;)  - p.s shouldnt i use 301 ?

Comment: check updated rule now. Yes you will be using 301 but for testing oyu must use 302 otherwise browser will cache wrong URLs and will show your wrong results.

Comment: hmm... this looks great but gives my an internal server error

Comment: I had a typo, it is fixed now. Try again.